# Select first child with specific class and hide element within it

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide the `span` element inside of the first `.lineB` element:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="lineA">I'm LineA</div>
    <div class="lineA">I'm LineA</div>
    <div class="lineB">I'm the first LineB <span>DONT SHOW ME</span></div>
    <div class="lineB">I'm LineB</div>
    <div class="lineB">I'm LineB</div>
    <div class="lineA">I'm LineA</div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
#main .lineB:first-of-type span {display: none}
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Comment: @Bijan - Not quite a duplicate. The answer supplied there does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps applying for all, and negating for all but first will fit your case

```css
.lineB{color:red}
.lineB ~ .lineB{color:inherit}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="lineA">I'm LineA</div>
    <div class="lineA">I'm LineA</div>
    <div class="lineB">I'm the first LineB</div>
    <div class="lineB">I'm LineB</div>
    <div class="lineB">I'm LineB</div>
    <div class="lineA">I'm LineA</div>
</div>
```

---

In your specific example you could just use `#main .lineB span{display:none}` since you only have a span inside the first.

The `:first-of-type` works on the element type (*the tag*) so it would match only an element that is the first of its type (*tag*) under the parent. Since all of your elements are `div` the `:first-of-type` matches the first div.

Extending my initial answer to handle this scenario you can do

```css
#main .lineB span{display:none}
#main .lineB ~ .lineB span{display:initial}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="lineA">I'm LineA</div>
    <div class="lineA">I'm LineA</div>
    <div class="lineB">I'm the first <span>hide me</span> LineB</div>
    <div class="lineB">I'm LineB <span> show me</span></div>
    <div class="lineB">I'm LineB</div>
    <div class="lineA">I'm LineA</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this isn't really working for me. I'll update my question with a bit more detail of what I'm trying to do

Comment: @FillipPeyton, that would be helpful to find a workaround as there is no selector for `:first-of-class`

Comment: Updated my question, but nevermind. I must have mistyped something when applying this to my situation: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/pfj7tv1f/

Comment: If you wanna adjust your answer to the updated question, I'll gladly select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In short: No. There is no `: first-of-class` selector. What you can do is:

1. Use `.lineA + .lineB` to to select every element with the class "lineB" that follows an element with class "lineA".

or

2. Use the `.lineB:first-of-type` selector and use a different element type for the two different classes (e.g. `p` and `div`).

or

3. Of course, use JavaScript.